# Cambiar de color elemento en un recyclerview al extraer los datos de una base de datos

Tags: android, recyclerview

Cabe señalar que al correr este codigo me vuelve todas rojas lo que quiero es leer el estauts de las mesas que estoy recuperando de la base de datos y que las ocupadas se pongan rojas y las libres se pongan verdes

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
    holder.txtViewNumeroMesa.setText(holder.mItem.getNum_mesa_app());
    holder.txtViewMesero.setText(holder.mItem.getNombremes_app());


    status = holder.mItem.getStatusmesa_app();
    Boolean cond = false;
    if (status == "Libre"){
        cond=true;
    }

        if (cond == true){
            holder.crdMesas.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        } else {
            holder.crdMesas.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }


    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (null != mListener) {
              
                mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(holder.mItem);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en esta comparación:

```
if (status == "Libre"){
    cond=true;
}
```

En Java, para comparar cadenas, tienes que usar `equals`, no `==`, por tanto la comparación debe ser así:

```
if (status.equals("Libre")){
    cond=true;
}
```

Dicho eso, das demasiadas vueltas para algo tan sencillo. Podrías hacer la asignación de color mediante un operador ternario y ahorrarte varias líneas de código. Por ejemplo:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
    holder.txtViewNumeroMesa.setText(holder.mItem.getNum_mesa_app());
    holder.txtViewMesero.setText(holder.mItem.getNombremes_app());    

    status = holder.mItem.getStatusmesa_app();
    /*
       El ternario reemplazará a los if ...
       Si el status es "Libre" la variable mColor será verde
       si no lo es, será roja
    */
    int mColor= status.equals("Libre") ? Color.GREEN : Color.RED;
    /*
       Y luego usas mColor para setear el color
       no hace falta nada más
    */
    holder.crdMesas.setBackgroundColor(mColor);

    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (null != mListener) {
              
                mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(holder.mItem);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**PD:**

La asignación puede hacerse también directamente, así:

```
int mColor= holder.mItem.getStatusmesa_app().equals("Libre") ? Color.GREEN : Color.RED;
```

Otra posibilidad, en cada de que sean varios colores, sería declarar una propiedad para el color en la clase que usas de modelo para llenar el RV.